# Erro de Sintaxe (Phyton)

Tags: python, string, datetime, dataframe, conversão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]eu estou fazendo um trabalho aqui com python utilizando o Pandas/Matplotlib/Seaborn/Numpy e queria entender porque que deu erro de sintaxe. Estou tentando modificar 3 colunas do meu dataset se String para Date Time.

```
datetime_cols = ['Start Time', 'End Time', 'Modified Date']
# método para transformar strings em date_time
def to_datetime(DataFrame, columns):
    for col in columns:
        DataFrame[col] = DataFrame[col].apply(lambda _: datetime.strptime(_,"%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

to_datetime(df, datetime_cols)
```

***- O erro dá na chamada do método***

Comment: Coloca a mensagem de erro **completa**. Com a mensagem de erro só de bater o olho já o informamos o problema.

Comment: o erro que dá é somente esse mesmo, o que tá no post.

Comment: Está faltando fechar um `)` ao final de `DataFrame[col] = DataFrame[col].apply(lambda _: datetime.strptime(_,"%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")` e você está usando um hole `_` que é um objeto de descarte de valores. Faça `DataFrame[col] = DataFrame[col].apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d,"%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))`

Comment: Foi! rsrs Faltava isso mesmo.

Comment: *Falei que era só mandar a mensagem de erro!*. Mentira, eu tive que ler a fonte para descobrir o erro, a mensagem não ajudou muito. :)

Comment: KKKKKKKKKKKKKKK

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo que a sugestão nos comentários tenha funcionado, ela não é performática em dataframes grandes por causa do uso do `apply()`, que embora seja mais rápido que um `for index, row in df.iterrows()`; é mais lento que a vetorização. Veja maiores detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

**Nota**: No link que passei, não olhe para a solução aceita como resposta, mas para a que recebeu 100 pontos pela qualidade da mesma.

Isso posto, segue outra solução:

### Criando DataFrame de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['11/4/2021', '12/4/2021', '13/4/2021'], "B": [1, 2, 3], "C": ['1/4/2021', '2/4/2021', '3/4/2021']})

>>> df
           A  B         C
0  11/4/2021  1  1/4/2021
1  12/4/2021  2  2/4/2021
2  13/4/2021  3  3/4/2021
```

### Verificando tipo das colunas

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      object
 1   B       3 non-null      int64
 2   C       3 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 200.0+ bytes
```

### Convertendo coluna A

```
>>> df["A"] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"], format='%d/%m/%Y')
>>> df
           A  B         C
0 2021-04-11  1  1/4/2021
1 2021-04-12  2  2/4/2021
2 2021-04-13  3  3/4/2021
```

### Verificando colunas novamente

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   B       3 non-null      int64
 2   C       3 non-null      object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
```